# Mocha runs nested beforeEach in unexpect order

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a test suite using Mocha with nested describe and beforeEach blocks.
When I run the tests I expect the outer beforeEach to run before the inner beforeEach

Here is some sample code

```
const expect = require('chai').expect

describe('Outer describe', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('Outer beforeEach is running!!!!');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    console.log('Outer afterEach is running!!!!');
  });

  it('Outter test', async () => {
    expect(true).to.be.true;
  });

  describe('Inner describe', () => {
    before(() => {
      console.log('Inner beforeEach is running!!!!');
    });

    after(() => {
      console.log('Inner afterEach is running!!!!');
    });

    // only used to simplify the output
    it.only('Inner test', async () => {
      expect(true).to.be.true;
    });
  })
});
```

He is the output from running the above tests

```
  Outer describe
    Inner describe
Inner beforeEach is running!!!!
Outer beforeEach is running!!!!
      ✓ Inner test
Outer afterEach is running!!!!
Inner afterEach is running!!!!
```

What I was expecting was

```
  Outer describe
    Inner describe
Outer beforeEach is running!!!!
Inner beforeEach is running!!!!
      ✓ Inner test
Inner afterEach is running!!!!
Outer afterEach is running!!!!
```

Is this expected behaviour?
My inner beforeEach depends on my outer beforeEach running before it, is this considered bad practice?

I'm using
Node 14.11.0
Mocha 8.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the output is not as expected is the inner describe is using a `before` instead of `beforeEach`

`before` only runs once before all tests in the describe block and `beforeEach` runs before every test in the describe block. This means the outer describe's `beforeEach` needs to run after the inner `before`